# How to Scroll a Div Without Scrollbars (mousewheel) (example included)

Tags: jquery, css

See: http://www.blackboard-consulting.com/partnerzy/

How am I able to create a div that scrolls like that, without the rest of the site moving?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty simple. The sidebar has a fixed position which prevents it from scrolling while the content can.

```
#sidebar{
   position:fixed;
   min-height:100%;
}
```